# Using overloaded + operator in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was practicing overloaded assignment operator use from derived class(Airplane in my case), and it worked just fine.
Problem i have is with overloaded + operator. It should just sum engine_power and seats from two Airplane objects, and then after sum flying_speed(bolded lines). And it really does go to the Base class overloaded + operator function when called from derived class (Vehicle::operator +(rhs);), but then Vehicle variable temp sums everything as it should do, but for some reason calls destructor right after and my Derived object's Base class atributes remain 0.Looking forward to any advice or suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
protected:
    int engine_power;
    int seats;
public:
    Vehicle(int engine_power, int seats)
        : engine_power{engine_power},seats{seats}{
            cout << "Vehicle constructor" << endl;
        }

    Vehicle &operator=(const Vehicle &rhs){
            cout << "Vehicle assignment" << endl;
        if (this==&rhs) 
            return *this;
        else{
            engine_power=rhs.engine_power;
            seats=rhs.seats;
            return *this;
            }
        }
    Vehicle operator+(const Vehicle &rhs){
        Vehicle temp{0,0};
        temp.engine_power=engine_power+rhs.engine_power;
        temp.seats=seats+rhs.seats;
        return temp;
    }
    ~Vehicle() {
        cout << "Vehicle destructor" << endl;
    }
};

class Airplane : public Vehicle {
private:
    int flying_speed;
public:
    Airplane(int a, int b, int flying_speed)
        : Vehicle{a,b}, flying_speed{flying_speed}{
            cout << "Airplane constructor" << endl;
        }

    Airplane &operator= (const Airplane &rhs){
        cout << "Airplane assignment" << endl;
        if (this!=&rhs){
            Vehicle::operator =(rhs);
            flying_speed=rhs.flying_speed;
            return *this;
        } else
            return *this;
    }
    Airplane operator+ (const Airplane &rhs) {
        Airplane temp{0,0,0};
        **Vehicle::operator +(rhs);**
        **temp.flying_speed=flying_speed+rhs.flying_speed;**
        return temp;
    }
    ~Airplane() {
        cout << "Airplane destructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
Airplane a1 {10,20,30};
Airplane a2 {10,22,33};
Airplane a3 = a1+a2;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure the destructors are called at the end of `main`s scope? What's your concern actually?

Comment: If there are special lines you want to point out in the code, please don't use markdown formatting. Add comments on those lines instead,

Comment: If you read [this reference of canonical implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations), for [binary arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators) (like `+`) it says that they should be implemented using the corresponding compound assignment operator. So the `operator+` function should be implemented using `operator+=`. Which I think would make your case simpler.

Comment: The result of your call of `Vehicle::operator+()` is not stored anywhere.   In the definition of `Airplane::operator+()` try `Airplane temp = Vehicle::operator+(rhs);  temp.flying_speed = flying_speed+rhs.flying_speed; return temp;`      More generally, you probably want `Vehicle::operator+()` to use some logic involving virtual functions to actually do their work.

Comment: @AleksandarRadosavljevic -- Any reason for the totally unnecessary user-defined assignment operators and destructors?  Implementing these functions for no reason just leaves you open to make silly errors, and possibly slow the code down.  The compiler versions for your classes are perfectly fine, and will copy efficiently and without error.  Also, don't use `*` to highlight code -- they could be confused for a pointer dereference or pointer declaration.

Comment: @Peter You found the problem, however, ```Airplane temp = Vehicle::operator+(rhs)``` is not valid, as we can't implicitly convert from ```Vehicle``` to ```Airplane```.

Comment: @StefanKssmr - I know.   But I intended that comment as a hint to get you closer to a solution, rather than a complete solution.    Another hint - an `Airplane &` or an `Airplane *`  CAN be implicitly converted (respectively) to a `Vehicle &` or a `Vehicle *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you don't store the result of your base class `Vehicle::operator+()` when called in the derived class. Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {
protected:
    int engine_power;
    int seats;
public:
    Vehicle(int engine_power, int seats)
        : engine_power{engine_power},seats{seats}{
            //cout << "Vehicle constructor" << endl;
        }

    Vehicle operator+(const Vehicle &rhs){
        Vehicle temp{0,0};
        temp.engine_power=engine_power+rhs.engine_power;
        temp.seats=seats+rhs.seats;
        return temp;
    }
};

class Airplane : public Vehicle {
private:
    int flying_speed;
public:
    Airplane(int a, int b, int flying_speed)
        : Vehicle{a,b}, flying_speed{flying_speed}{
            //cout << "Airplane constructor" << endl;
        }
    Airplane operator+ (const Airplane &rhs) {
        Airplane temp{0,0,0};
        static_cast<Vehicle&>(temp) = Vehicle::operator +(rhs);
        temp.flying_speed=flying_speed+rhs.flying_speed;
        return temp;
    }
    void print() const {
        cout << " power " << engine_power 
             << " seats " << seats  
             << " speed " << flying_speed 
            << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Airplane a1 {10,20,30};
    Airplane a2 {10,22,33};
    Airplane a3 = a1+a2;
    a3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
 `power 20 seats 42 speed 63`

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/36WKTacPr)